# Where to find Azure Mobile Apps Push API Documentation?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I can't find any documentation for the  `push/installations/` REST API. Is there any ?

For example in my code I use that statement to register my Azure Mobile Apps Client on the Push Notification Hub.

```
// Register with NotificationHub
            DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation = await client.InvokeApiAsync<DeviceInstallation, DeviceInstallation>(
                $"/push/installations/{client.InstallationId}",
                installation,
                HttpMethod.Put,
                new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

But I want to know how to `DELETE` a previous registration but don't know how.

Thanks for any help.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to know how to DELETE a previous registration but don't know how.

For deleting the Installation, you could send a request as follows:

```
DELETE /push/installations/{InstallationId}
```

For more details, you could check the method `DeleteInstallationAsync` and `CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync` under [PushHttpClient.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/8f0fc245f29c5b3245ce27e8428b0f4a90b948bc/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Push/PushHttpClient.cs).

Moreover, for creating/deleting a installation, you could just use the following build-in methods:

```
client.GetPush().RegisterAsync
client.GetPush().UnregisterAsync
```

Details you could just follow [Add push notifications to Xamarin.Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push).

Comment: Would that be sufficient , too? await client.InvokeApiAsync<DeviceInstallation, DeviceInstallation>(
                    $"/push/installations/{client.InstallationId}",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.Delete, null);

Comment: Per my understanding, they are equivalent. `/push/installations` is just the build-in custom HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the push installation exists? For example when I delete the registration in the azure portal my client gets not notice of that. So I seek for a way to re-register if the installation is deleted or invalid.

Comment: For a simple way, you could check the **Device Registrations** of your Notifications Hub under Server Explorer via Visual Studio, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer#self-diagnose-tips).

Comment: Moreover, `PUT /push/installations/{InstallationId}` would create or update the installation, the server side code for installation management would similar to [NotificationInstallationsController.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/04d75cadc137cc478f98edfa1fa5b868e5548dfd/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/Controllers/NotificationInstallationsController.cs).